# How to create a views tree and place at home page in drupal 7?

Tags: 7, views

I want to create a forum using the [Views Tree](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_tree) module, which I've installed/enabled. But I don't know how to create it as shown in image below and then place at home page. Here is a screenprint like I want to create:

[image]

Any suggestion on this?

Comment: Are you looking forward to add just regular menu links? Because in your image above, you seem to include links to files, images, etc.

Comment: Have you read  **views tree** documentation ? https://www.drupal.org/node/1493366